# Проблемы с конфигурацией Log4j

Tags: java, логирование, log4j

Имеется следующий xml файл конфигурации log4j:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<Configuration trace="true" debug="true" info="true" warn="true">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d %-5p [%t] %C{2} (%F:%L) - %m%n"/>
        </Console>
        <MyCustomAppender name="toStringProperty" >
            <PatternLayout pattern=":%m%n" />
        </MyCustomAppender>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
        </Root>

        <!-- <Logger name="com" level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
        </Logger> -->

        <Logger name="com.oaks" level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="toStringProperty"/>
        </Logger>
    </Loggers> 
</Configuration>
```

Проблема заключается в том, что уровень логирования для `Root` лога зависит от свойства `level` у логера `"com.oaks"`, что само по себе очень странно.

Соответственно, если необходимо в консоль выводить лог уровня `debug` и выше, приходится ставить такой же уровень у кастомного лога, а для него требуется уровень `info`.

Пробовал создать отдельный лог для консоли (обрамлен комментарием), но эффект тот же самый.

Прошу объяснить, почему такое может происходить и как тогда необходимо правильно настроить уровни для логов.

Comment: А сам rootLogger используется? Где? Как инициализируете?

Comment: @SergeyMitrofanov. Возможно я чего-то не понимаю, но логер инициализирую вот так: public static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(%className%);

Comment: Если %className% лежит в пакете com.oaks или во вложенном, по отношении к нему, то он будет наследовать настройки логгера для com.oaks, если не определен его персональный логгер. А вот для логгеров из пакета com.foo должен срабатывать или логгер для com или root. Сам рутовый логгер можно получить отдельно  Logger ROOT_LOG =LogManager.getRootLogger(); в любом классе

Comment: @SergeyMitrofanov. Однако это не объясняет, почему level у кастомного логера нивелирует level у рутового логгера, т.к. рут в иерархии находится на самом верху.

Comment: В данном случае все наоборот. Почитайте первоисточник. Там все описано и в таблицах примеры есть https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/architecture.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо Peter Slusar и Sergey Mitrofanov.

Суть конфига свелась к следующему:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration trace="true" debug="true" info="true" warn="true">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d %-5p [%t] %C{2} (%F:%L) - %m%n"/>
        </Console>

        <MyCustomAppender name="toStringProperty" >
            <PatternLayout pattern=":%m%n" />
            <!-- здесь появился фильтр -->
            <ThresholdFilter level="INFO" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
        </MyCustomAppender>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>

        <Root level="debug" >
        <!-- оба аппендера находятся в рут-логе -->
            <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="toStringProperty"/>
        </Root>

    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Answer (score 2):

Здравствуйте
XML конфигурации с пояснениями:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d %-5p [%t] %C{2} (%F:%L) - %m%n" />
        </Console>
        <Console name="toStringProperty" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d %-5p [%t] %C{2} (%F:%L) - %m 'toStringProperty'%n" />
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="com.oaks.A" level="info" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="toStringProperty" />
        </Logger>
        <Root level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Добавим проверочный класс:

```
public class A {
    private Logger logA = LogManager.getLogger(this.getClass());

    public static void main(String... d) {

        A a = new A();
        a.logA.debug("debug a");
        a.logA.info("info a");
        a.logA.error("error a");

        B b = a.new B();
        b.logB.debug("debug b");
        b.logB.info("info b");
        b.logB.error("error b");
    }

    class B {
        private Logger logB = LogManager.getLogger(this.getClass());
    }
}
```

итак:

когда Вы указываете уровень регистратора вы отфильтровываете сообщения(данные переданные объекту типа Logger).принцип фильтрования следующий:все сообщения уровнем выше указанного будут отброшены(и соответственно не пройдут дальше!(к примеру к корневому логгеру)) 
Уровни фильтрации:

> (верхний) ALL -> TRACE -> DEBUG ->INFO -> WARN -> ERROR -> FATAL -> OFF

Из вышесказанного Ваш настроенный на более низкий уровень персональный логгер отбрасывает сообщения уровня DEBUG.

Comment: Благодарю за объяснение. Подскажите, как тогда необходимо настроить логирование, чтобы в кастомный лог выводить сообщения уровнем ниже, чем в консоль?

Comment: @I.Perevoz Для решения этой задачи вам стоит разобраться в [фильтрах](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/filters.html)